# Grammatically correct sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> He has born on Tuesday.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
I want to express that the person I mention was born on that day.  Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"He was born on a Tuesday"-if TUESDAY is the fact that needs highlighting.
Else, "He was born on Tuesday"-if it's a recent Tuesday you are referring.

Answer (score 1):

"He has born on Tuesday," is incorrect.

"He was born on Tuesday,"  Is correct and used if the birth was within 7 days.  If, however, you only want to express which day of the week one was born, you would add an article: "He was born on a Tuesday."